# Android: How to access Apache server in local network when device has no internet?

Tags: android, apache, networking, router

My android-app needs communication with an local apache/PHP-server. It sends request like these `http://my-server/somefolder/file.php`

This worked fine so far, but now I tested the system while the router has no internet access. Then it cannot access the local PHP files. When I try to access the pages via the android-browser, it gives me the not-found-error. However, I can access the pages on my PC, so only the android-tablets have the issue.

I'm also searching the problem on my router, but I'm not sure where the problem is.

Thank you for any help/tips.

Comment: how is your device connected to the router? if it is wifi then your PC also connected with the same wifi router?

Comment: @Ashok They are all in the same network connected via wifi to the same router.
I think i found the problem: My android device has no DNS server, my PC does. When I replace the 'my-server' with the IP-adress 192.168.1.93, it works. But I don't know how to set the DNS on android.

Comment: probably this helps you https://www.witopia.net/?faq-item=how-do-i-set-the-dns-on-android-devices